# Unable to run jar in directory as user

Tags: sudo

I have a user with sudo access, I am moving a jar file into another directory and then making sure the directory and its contents belong to that user before trying to run the jar as that user, for example

```
  #!/bin/bash
  WORKDIR=/app/services/myapp
  sudo mv myjar.jar $WORKDIR

  sudo chmod -R 755 $WORKDIR
  sudo chown -R appuser:appuser $WORKDIR

  sudo -S su - appuser -c "java -jar $WORKDIR/myjar.jar"
```

However I get the following

```
  Error: Unable to access jarfile /app/services/myapp/myjar.jar
```

What could be the issue? I notice I can ls the $WORKDIR (with sudo) but I can't cd into it (even with sudo)

Comment: Has `appuser` read access to `/app` and `/app/services`?

Comment: `/app` has 754 and `/app/services` has 755

Comment: Aha ok `/app` also required 755, thankyou :)